# How to add multiple lists in a table in jsp page

Tags: spring-mvc

I have data in three Array lists summaryList,DescriptionList and statusList. These lists i am getting from my controller page. I want to populate the data in table format have each column for each list from a jsp page.

i tried below code:
Controller.java:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 summaryList.add(summary);
descriptionList.add(description);
satList.add(sat);
model.put("summary", summaryList);
model.put("description", descriptionList);
model.put("sat", satList);
return new ModelAndView("DefectsJira", "model", model);
```

jsp code:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Issue Key</th>
     <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${summary}" varStatus="theCount" >
    <tr><td>${listItem}</td><td>${description[theCount.index]}</td><td>${sat[theCount.index]}</td></tr>
</c:forEach> 

</table>

Expected output is:
Summary     Description     Status
Summarydata DescriptionData StatusData

Actual output:
Summary Description Status
```

Comment: That could be happen because in summary list there might be 2 record and in for each loop you are using that list. Can you put exact data what you want to display ?Or there will be always same  number of data in all the list ?

Comment: All the three lists will have same number of data. Data can be anything. I want each list data to print in respective columns.